# Extracting a silhouette from Image for Android and iOS, best option? OpenCV, OpenGL, other..?

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, opencv, opengl-es

I want to make an app for iPhone and Android. The main activity will be extracting a silhouette from a photo (a photo taken with the device's camera). What will be the best option?

I've read a lot about this, and I think that the best option could be OpenCV (now they have an official port for iOS too), but I'm not sure because I don't have any experience with this. I need your advice.

Maybe OpenGL could be a better option? (GPUImage Framework for iOS and JOGL for Android, for example). Or maybe there are libraries that are more simple for this task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is a rendering technology.

OpenCV is a library for digital imaging processing.

OpenCV is clearly the only real option that you have, there are many [tutorial](http://www.google.com/webhp#q=opencv+silhouette+recognition) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489091/finding-people-silhouette-in-opencv-c) on the internet about this.